# Parameter String in Filter Examples Rapidminer

Tags: parameters, rapidminer

I have a dataset from twitter. I need to remove tweets related to an specific word.
I used 'Filter Examples' operator and selected for 'Condition class' -> 'attribute_value'. I followed the Rapidminer guide but it's not working.
It  says:

"This parameter is available when the parameter 'attribute_value_filter' is selected as condition class. The condition format is an Attribute name, followed by a comparison function and a value to match. 
Nominal Attributes can be compared by = and != with an arbitrary string, which can also include a regular expression."

Hence, I typed:
`text{=strike!=}`
also tried:
`text=strike!=`

**'text'** is the name of my attribute
**'strike'** is the word I want to remove.

However, I'm getting this error:

[image: Error rapidminer]

Can someone please point out what I am doing wrong? I've tried several variations, but for some idiot reason it's not working.

Please be kind I'm quite new at this and I really need it for my thesis. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

to filter out tweets containing a certain word, you need to use regular expression syntax.
The most simple expression would be:

`text != .*strike.*`
but this would also filter out texts where *strike* is part of another word, so
probably better suited would be:

```
text != .*\sstrike[\s\.\!\,\.\:$].
```

reading as: filter out any example in *text* where before strike are arbitrary characters and a white space and followed by either a white space,a punctuation character or end of line.